# Is a process the same as a Goroutine in Golang?

Tags: memory, go, process, goroutine

For the following code:

```
func main() {
    goRtns := runtime.NumGoroutine()
    fmt.Println("goroutines:", goRtns)
}
```

The output is `1`. But this is within a "process," with no goroutines being explicitly called:

"In computing, a process is an instance of a computer program that is being executed. It contains the program code and its current activity. Depending on the operating system (OS), a process may be made up of multiple threads of execution that execute instructions concurrently."

Also from the excellent "How goroutines work" blog post by Krishna Sundarram: http://blog.nindalf.com/how-goroutines-work/

"The creation of a goroutine does not require much memory - only 2kB of stack space. They grow by allocating and freeing heap storage as required."

My question is this, then: the instance of code that is running (my simple main.go function) is counted as a goroutine by the runtime library. Am I to assume that the parent process is treated as a go routine, with the same rules of memory allocation, garbage collection, etc? Would it be wise to assume reading a fact about a goroutine's execution is analogous to the overarching go process that runs it? With respect to the second quote on goroutines above, this sounds like a process growing/shrinking its stack space as a program executes which is a standard paradigm in programming.

Do go processes and routines share the same rules? Or am I just missing something about the reported number of goroutines.

Comment: Just forget about "process", this is an OS/userspace/layman term. In GO everything is a goroutine and these are scheduled to threads. There are no "go processes" (whatever that could mean).

Comment: To expand on that a little, when you run a go program it's just like running anything else – it's only one process (unless the program explicitly creates other processes). There's always at least one goroutine in a Go program (the one that runs `main`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is a process the same as a Goroutine in Golang?

You are using the wrong term `process` here. In GO everything is a goroutine. as [Volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266756/volker) said. and you can see gouroutine definition from [here](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1) :

> A goroutine is a lightweight thread managed by the Go runtime.

for example in your code

```
func main() {
    goRtns := runtime.NumGoroutine()
    fmt.Println("goroutines:", goRtns)
}
```

this has only one goroutine because it has only `main` function and inside there are no `go` calling here. it just print the something from given variable.

another example if you have `go` called in your function `main` :

```
func main() {

    result := sq(sq(sq(gen(1, 2, 3, 4))))

    numGoroutines := runtime.NumGoroutine()
    fmt.Println("number goroutine = ", numGoroutines)

    fmt.Println(<-result)
    fmt.Println(<-result)
    fmt.Println(<-result)
    fmt.Println(<-result)

}
```

you can find sq and gen function [here](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines). Now the `runtime.NumGoroutine()` will have 5 gorutine. Since inside function `gen` and `sq` we have `go` called and we combine theme here the total would be 4 + the `main` the final result is 5.

Answer (score 3):

You have to be careful about the term *process* in Go. You quoted a definition about operating system entities called *processes* that will be recognised very widely. Many people will understand that usage.

But the term is overloaded. The work of C.A.R. Hoare also matters to us: in his *Communicating Sequential Processes* (CSP) algebra, the term *process* refers to something small - much more like a super-lightweight thread. His algebra is in a category of mathematics called *process algebra*.

So it is fair to assume that a *goroutine* is Go's implementation of a CSP *process*.

Go is like a much older language, Occam, in this respect. In Occam a process means a CSP process. Occam was widely used for bare-metal (I.e. no operating system) embedded programming and so there was never any ambiguity over the term *process*.